# Using CSS Selector to get row element

Tags: css-selectors, selenium-ide

This is my code

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            <span>Cloud Email Security</span>
            <input id="productLine_software-0" name="productLine_software" value="Cloud Email Security" type="hidden"/>
        </div>          
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <span>Core</span>
            <input id="productCategory_software-0" name="productCategory_software" value="Core" type="hidden"/>
        </div>      
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <span>Cloud Antispam</span>
            <input id="softwareName_software-0" name="softwareName_software" value="Cloud Antispam" type="hidden"/>
        </div>      
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>
                    <input id="select_boolean_software_1" type="checkbox" value="1" name="select_boolean_software"/>                        
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            <span>Cloud Email Security</span>
            <input name="productLine_software" value="Cloud Email Security" type="hidden"/>
        </div>          
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <span>Core</span>
            <input id="productCategory_software-0" name="productCategory_software" value="Core" type="hidden"/>
        </div>          
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <span>Cloud Email Security</span>
            <input name="softwareName_software" value="Cloud Email Security" type="hidden"/>
        </div>          
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>
                    <input id="select_boolean_software_1" type="checkbox" value="1" name="select_boolean_software"/>                        
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am using this CSS selector code in Selenium

```
css=tr:contains('Cloud Email Security & Content Control') input[type = 'checkbox']
```

It always select the first row instead of 2nd one. Any thoughts? (I deleted remainig  tags becoz the code was really long)

Comment: You should never use such selectors, if there is a slight chance, that there is another way.

Comment: Can you not target this with any other selector?  First child, last child, nth-child etc

Comment: I tried many other combinations, but none worked. I want to search for tr which has td with a specific value and specific name and then I need to click on input checkbox on the same tr.

Comment: And you don't have control over the HTML output I assume?

Comment: I don't have any control over the HTML

Comment: There is more than one such cell, so you're going to have to tell Selenium which one to use. What other combinations have you tried?

Comment: I tried //tr[//input[@value="Cloud Antispam" and @name = "softwareName_software"]]//input[@type="checkbox"] but it still picks first cell instead of correct second one

Comment: I updated my code, I want to click input[@type = "checkbox"] for that tr which td with input[@name= "softwareName_software" and @value = "Cloud Email Security"] I tried above condition, it still picks first checkbox all the time.

Comment: Hi BoltClock, any thoughts?

Comment: If you want to select the second child of the `table` then probably you can use the `table:nth-child(2)` css selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a few few attempts involving the tr tag, both using CSS and XPATH, but seems to me the tr is acting weird in the locator.

If you don't explicitly need to use the tr, and instead can go for the checkbox following your unique input, try this

`xpath=//input[@name='softwareName_software' and @value='Cloud Email Security']/following::input[@type='checkbox']`

Comment: Glad to hear it helped :)

Comment: Any ideas why TR tag was not working as expected ? In theory, it should

Comment: Nah. When I figured the tr didn't work as I expected it to (theory) I just moved on to find an alternative solution. The table structure is a bit complicated; maybe the Selenium implementation can't handle all variants as expected, or maybe there is some additional rules we don't know about.